# Unable to install VisualStudioCode custom theme (.vsix)

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, themes, vsix

So I made a custom theme for VScode, and I just want to install it for personal use, not to be put on the marketplace.  Once I customized it, and edited the package.json and README.md files appropriately, I opened the terminal and ran these lines of code, one after the other.  This is my first time making a theme and therefore first time running these commands (in case that matters):

```
npm i -g vsce
```

Next:

```
vsce package
```

I then saw the .vsix file created in my explorer on the left hand side. The text appears dim, I'm not sure if that is an indication that something is wrong... is it?

[image]

I right clicked on the file and selected 'Install Extension VSIX' on the bottom

[image]

There was no indication that anything had happened, even after clicking install several times.
After that, I tried finding the theme in the color theme searcher, and couldn't find it there either, leading me to assume that it did not install.  I also tried doing it through the terminal, using:

```
code --install-extension dv1-0.0.1.vsix
```

However, I was greeted by the response: "zsh: command not found: code".  I was following this video tutorial to install my custom theme: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QCqWzb-9Sy8

The section about installing your theme starts at 11:05.  Is there something I have to download to utilize that 'code' command?  Regardless I feel like the first installation method I tried should have worked.

In case this matters, I will mention that a "vsc-extension-quickstart.md" file was created as well.  I did not find it helpful.

Any way in which you can help is much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I installed the 'code' command, so I ran

```
code --install-extension dv1-0.0.1.vsix
```

in my terminal and this time it told me that the current VScode version was incompatible, so I went to my package.json and changed the version to 1.51.1 and I was able to install my theme. However, now when I look for the theme in the theme search, I am not seeing it.  I know it was installed because it says so in the terminal.

[image]

Any idea where I can find and use my theme? Thanks

Comment: To use code from shell, add it to path https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line

Comment: That worked, and after re-running that last command in terminal, I found out the version in my package.json was incompatible.  I fixed that, and now it is installed! However, when I search for it in my themes, it is not appearing.  How can I find it? Thanks for your help

Comment: Can't access video right now, I suggest describing the command and files involved as text  in your question so others can't help

Comment: is the extension stored in the user extension directory? If you run the extension in development mode does it work? Have you tried installing a vsix file with the toolbar of the Extension Bar? Have you unzipped the vsix file to see what is inside?

Comment: Strangely enough, even though it said I installed it via terminal, I just installed it again via right clicking on the extension and clicking install from there. Now it appears in my themes and is working!